# Enviar multiplas imagens via Curl

Tags: php, libcurl, file-upload

Olá, estou precisando enviar via Curl múltiplas imagens, que serão recebidas em uma API, só que na API ele recebe de uma forma específica, na qual eu não estou conseguindo enviar pelo Curl. Segue forma que a API recebe a imagem:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
                $arquivo_enviar = $file['name'];
                $extensao_arquivo = strrchr($arquivo_enviar, '.');
                $arquivo_enviar = md5(time().$arquivo_enviar) . $extensao_arquivo;
                if (in_array($file['type'], $allowedExts)) {
                    if ($file["error"] > 0) {
                        http_response_code(406);
                    } else{
                        $de = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'everton/api/uploads/produtos_'.md5($data->authenticator).$id_loja.'/'. $arquivo_enviar;
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $de);
                        $caminho[$i] = 'http://192.168.110.4/everton/api/uploads/produtos_'.md5($data->authenticator).$id_loja.'/'.$arquivo_enviar;
```

no caso, o $_FILES, contém as seguintes informações:

```
Array(  
   [file] => Array
   (
       [name] => blog_pense_digital_gif.gif
       [type] => image/gif
       [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpkoZilo
       [error] => 0
       [size] => 761850
   ))
```

No momento, estou enviando, pelo Curl, da seguinte forma:

```
$url = $url_api.'produto/'.$produtoId.'/uploadimage?authenticator='.$token;
            $imagens = count($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $imagens; $i++){
                $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
                $filedata = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];
                if ($filedata != ''){
                    $headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data");
                    $postfields = array("filedata" => "@$filedata", "filename" => $filename);
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    $options = array(
                        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
                        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
                        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
                        CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $filesize,
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
                    );
                    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
                    print curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                }
}
```

Só que a API está recebendo o meu arquivo da seguinte forma:

```
Array(
[filename] => Sem título.jpg)
Array(
[filedata] => Array
    (
        [name] => phpKERYcS
        [type] => application/octet-stream
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpggdoxS
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 168099
    ))
```

O filename está sendo enviado separado do resto, via POST, e o filedata, com as informações do arquivo via FILE

Comment: Por favor, pode inserir seu código em um codePen para que possamos visualizar melhor e assim podermos lhe ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Segue solução:

```
 $produtoId = $_POST['produtoId'];       
            $url = $url_api.'produto/'.$produtoId.'/uploadimage?authenticator='.$token; 
            $total_imagens = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
            for ($i=0; $i < $total_imagens; $i++) { 
                $target_path = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
                $filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
                $filedata = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $postfields = array("filedata" => "@$filedata;type=".$filetype, "filename" => $filename);
               // $postfields = array('files' => $target_path);
                $filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
                $ch = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $filesize);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:multipart/form-data'));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                print curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);  
            }
```